# how to differentiate searched or created by first_or_create

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to differentiate searched or created by first_or_create.

```
record = MasterRecord.where(:name=>'test_data').firest_or_create

# and i want differentiate searched or created like this.
# but there is no created_record? method
if record.created_record?
    render :status=>200, :json => record.to_json
else
    render :status=>409, :json => record.to_json
end
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 5):

A workaround will be to use `first_or_initialize` instead `first_or_create` and then use the `new_record?` as follows:

```
record = MasterRecord.where(:name=>'test_data').first_or_initialize

created_record = record.new_record?
record.save! if record.new_record?

if created_record
    render :status=>200, :json => record.to_json
else
    render :status=>409, :json => record.to_json
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If record can't be found the return will be `[]`, so you can play with `tap`.
Something like this:

```
created = false
record = MasterRecord.where(:name=>'test_data').tap {|x| created = true if x.empty?}.first_or_create
if created
  ...
```

Comment: I did'nt know tap.  I searched tap and I know it's very nice. thanks.